# iOS InApp Purchase not working in the ipa

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, payment, ipa

In our application, InApp Purchases are not working properly, these are working if I am directly running from Xcode and I can easily made the purchases and proceed further.

But if I created ipa and then from that build I tried, it is not working. I have checked that all agreements have been accepted and all information in tax and banking section is updated.

So could anyone help me here!

I am just at the phase of launching the app to the AppStore so early help would be appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: Does your Production / App Store Identifier have `In-App Purchase` ticked, and does your Provisioning Profile show this? After any changes to these, you will need to get Xcode to download the latest profiles, via Preferences.

Comment: Try using TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

When app is installed from xCode, you can test sandbox iAP, but when app is installed other than xCode, like Diawi link or installed from appStore, All iAP have to be submitted and approved from appStore.

so when submitted new app, please also submit your all iAP products as well

Comment: Shahbaz Ali  iAP submission would only require when we publish app to the App store for review, but with Diawi links it should work properly with approval. And this works for this app earlier and all other apps as well.